# how to solve requested resources not found in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

[image]

I am working on a project something like exam system here everything is working fine but when i go to **students** section or module it gives me following error. Please help me. Any help will be appreciated.
here is my route

```
Route::resource('students', 'StudentController');
```

and here is my controller index method

```
 public function index()
    {
        $students = Student::all();
        return view('student.index', compact('students'));
    }
```

Comment: It could comes from the .htaccess (apache) configuration file or the route cache. Try running php artisan optimize

Comment: LogicException ?[49;22m : [33mUnable to prepare route [api/user] for
serialization. Uses Closure.

Comment: it gives me this error

Comment: hold on a second, if i change mu route name then its working

Comment: can you tell me why

Comment: @TanvirAhmed Can you check `public folder` directory name `students` exists?

Comment: yes i create a folder named students for storing the images of students

Comment: @TanvirAhmed That is why the issue occurs. Please change the directory name `student` instead of `students`.

Comment: yes i already changed the folder and thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

As You said project something like exam system so I have doubt you have created `students` folder inside a public folder.

When you have a path with the same name as a directory in the `public folder`

If same then you need to change the `directory` name or route pathname as your requirement.

Thanks.